# C++ template class call own constructor from static helper

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods

I've run into a pickle with a template class:

```
template <
          class N
         >
class Edge
{
  public:

    typedef std::shared_ptr<N> N_ptr;

    Edge
    (
      N_ptr node
     )
    {
       //...
    }

    template <class Archive>
    static Edge<N> * load_and_allocate( Archive & ar )
    {
      N_ptr node;
      ar( node );
      return new ::template Edge<N>( node );
    }
};
```

The method load_and_allocate is required by [cereal](http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/pointers.html) for deserialization of objects without a default empty constructor.

For the return line for load_and_allocate, the compiler throws:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = Edge<Concept>; _Args = {}]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:497:3:   required from ‘static void std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = Edge<Concept>*; _Size = long unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:545:7:   required from ‘void std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = Edge<Concept>*; _Size = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:607:7:   required from ‘void std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = Edge<Concept>*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = Edge<Concept>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc:541:8:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = Edge<Concept>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Edge<Concept> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:647:4:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = Edge<Concept>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Edge<Concept> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/local/include/cereal/types/vector.hpp:83:5:   [ skipping 31 instantiation contexts ]
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:525:8:   required from ‘std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, _Tp*, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = SemanticGraph<Concept>; _Alloc = std::allocator<SemanticGraph<Concept> >; _Args = {const char (&)[16]}; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:997:35:   required from ‘std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<SemanticGraph<Concept> >; _Args = {const char (&)[16]}; _Tp = SemanticGraph<Concept>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:317:64:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Alloc = std::allocator<SemanticGraph<Concept> >; _Args = {const char (&)[16]}; _Tp = SemanticGraph<Concept>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:599:39:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::allocate_shared(const _Alloc&, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = SemanticGraph<Concept>; _Alloc = std::allocator<SemanticGraph<Concept> >; _Args = {const char (&)[16]}]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:615:42:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp1> std::make_shared(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = SemanticGraph<Concept>; _Args = {const char (&)[16]}]’
/home/alex/projects/Icarus/trunk/Api/Daemon/../ConnectionHandler/../../Processes/Controller/../../Datatypes/Domain/../../Handlers/SemanticNodeFactory/SemanticNodeFactory.hpp:34:82:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Edge<Concept>::Edge()’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h:77:7: note: candidates are:
candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Edge<Relation>::Edge(const Edge<Relation>&)
```

Message repeats for other template (Concept & Relation).

Same thing happens for:

```
return new ::template Edge<N>( node );
```

and

```
return new Edge<N>::template Edge( node );
```

or

```
return new Edge<N>::template Edge<N>( node );
```

or

```
return new Edge<N>( node );
```

In fact, most complain about the qualifier, with only the first return statement not creating any errors about the qualifier.

Could someone please explain why is it not picking up the only available constructor, and ignores the parameter I pass to it?

Weirdly enough, if I declare an empty default public constructor:

```
Edge( ){ }
```

It compiles without an error.

Comment: I think simply calling `new Edge(node)` will do what you need.

Comment: @Arkadiy No, I'm afraid the exact same error is produced

Comment: The code works in a [minimal compiling example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7159c962614b794) for me. The issue could be related to your file structure (header files). You can use the *injected-class-name* `Edge` without template arguments inside the class.

Comment: How `Archive` type looking like, and how do you call `load_and_allocate(Archive & ar )`?

Comment: @Drop I don't call load_and_allocate, its called by lib cereal upon de-serialization, instead of calling a default constructor.

Comment: @DyP It doesn't seem to make any difference. I'm guessing the problem is then somewhere else (vector/shared_ptr) and not within my own class?

Comment: Your errors refer to vector: `required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = Edge<Concept>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Edge<Concept> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’`, yet the code you published has no mention of any vectors. What are we missing?

Comment: @Arkadiy The owner & specialization of class Edge<N> is a vector. So, for class Concept:     std::vector<Edge<Concept>> _edges;
and for class Relation:    std::vector<Edge<Relation>> _edges;

Comment: There you go. To use a class with std::vector you have to have a default constructor. Oh, and the default constructor is not generated for you if you wrote some other constructors.

Comment: @Arkadiy I am 99% certain this code worked before without a default constructor. My guess was that it had something to do with the template class not constructed properly, but you're right, adding an default constructor works, albeit I would have liked to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't have to have a default constructor to use T with std::vector, you'll just be limited in what methods you can call on it.

Comment: @isce-phoenix is right: only some operations require a default constructor. Try to make sure you don't use any of them. I can't figure out what exactly triggers the requirement for `resize` in your code. I wish we did not get `skipping 31 instantiation contexts` in the errors.

Comment: Could it be an assignment of a vector to a vector, or a copy of a vector to another vector? I don't call resize anywhere (unless called automatically), I get iterators and push_back/remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing a vector of T requires T to be default constructible or you to provide a default value as a second argument to 'resize'.

In your case Edge is not default constructible.

Comment: Sure, I see that in the error message too - but where is the code that tries to make a vector of Edge?

Comment: It looks like it's somewhere inside 'cereal' lib.